# Mechanics of a weighted rod held at one and

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, statics

[image]

[image]

We need to show that the tension in the rope, T, is = to 2Mgcos(theta)

I've taken Moments about A but keep getting T = (1/2)Mgcos(theta).

I've ignored the moments at C as they are in equilibrium already I'm assuming. Meaning (1.5a)Rc = (1.5a)2Mgcos(theta). Including them in my calculation doesn't make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The sequence in which you wrote out the formulas on your handwritten diagram is unclear (which would be a good reason to write them all out [in MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)), but it looks like you have only accounted for the moment of the uniform rod without including the moment of the point mass attached to it. Writing down each step in order from top to bottom with written explanations for each step can be very helpful in finding where you go wrong.

Comment: Math isn't the issue here... it is physics.  This question should be migrated to physics.SE.

Answer (score 1):

If you drop a perpendicular from any point on $AB$ to the horizontal line, you will see that the angle between that line and a line perpendicular to $AB$ is $\theta$ because both are complementary to the same angle.

The weight of the beam operates at the center of mass of the beam which is $a$ units from the origin. This gives us that the tension of the rope has to counter-balance the weight of the beam acting at $a$ and the weight of the object at $1.5a$. This gives:

$$2aT=1.5a(2M)g\cos{\theta}+Mga\cos{\theta}\implies 2aT=4Mg\cos{\theta}\implies T=2Mg\cos{\theta}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Why do we not include the moment force involving the reaction at C going anticlockwise? Meaning 1.5a x Rc. Is it because there is no reaction at C?

Comment: @AhmedHussain-Shah You have to be careful with Newton's third law. When you draw a free body diagram you only consider external forces. If there was a supporting member at $C$ then there would be a reaction. The weight of the object at $C$ and the beam provide external forces and the tension in the rope is the reactive force.